# How to create Web App bot in azure using programmatically?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I just created web app bot manually in azure and its working fine. I need to create web app bot **programmatically using node.js**. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the documentation provided on their website? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart

Comment: @sid8491 Yes I tried but its only for local development. I looking for create web app bot programmatically in azure.

Comment: The conversational logic for your bot is hosted as a web service. The Bot Builder SDK uses restify, a popular framework for building web services, to create the bot's web server. The SDK is also compatible with Express and the use of other web app frameworks is possible with some adaption.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic bot creation is not an option right now, but this is a high priority for the Bot Framework team and will be available soon.  Please watch the Bot Framework blog for announcements. http://blog.botframework.com