# Issue in create a Azure BOT using Rest API

Tags: azure, botframework

I am trying to create an Azure bot using Azure Rest API.

I am hitting this API (PUT Request) via the code by replacing the subscription id, resource group name

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupId}
/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/{botName}?api-version=2018-07-12
```

Request body as follows

```
{"location":"global","properties":{"displayName":"{botName}","description":"{botName}","iconUrl":"https://docs.botframework.com/static/devportal/client/images/bot-framework-default.png","endpoint":"{endPoint}","msaAppId":"{app ID}"}}
```

However I am getting the error as

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidBotData",
        "message": "Bot is not valid. Errors: RuntimeVersion is required.  See https://aka.ms/bot-requirements for detailed requirements."
    }
}
```

I tried using nodejs (arm-botservice SDK) to create the bot using the same parameters (of course changing the parameters according to our azure portal ids) but I am still getting the same error. I guess internally it will call the same API as above.

Any help would be appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: [Programmatic bot creation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/381) can be done with [az bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bot-create) within the Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to do it.

I added the kind parameter and then it worked.

Following is the request

```
{"location":"global",kind="registration","properties":{"displayName":"{botName}","description":"{botName}","iconUrl":"https://docs.botframework.com/static/devportal/client/images/bot-framework-default.png","endpoint":"{endPoint}","msaAppId":"{app ID}"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic bot creation can not be done with REST at this time.

[How to create Web App bot in azure using programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059996/how-to-create-web-app-bot-in-azure-using-programmatically)

Use az cli as @joey-cai mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels resource, add the following JSON to the resources section of your template.

```
{
"name": "string",
"type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels",
"apiVersion": "2018-07-12",
"location": "string",
"tags": {},
"sku": {
"name": "string"
},
"kind": "string",
"properties": {
"channelName": "string"
 }
}
```

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.botservice/2018-07-12/botservices/channels