# Is there any way to create and manage Azure bot service and app registration resource using the Azure REST API instead of Azure CLI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-bot-service

I was able to find a solution to create/manage Azure bot service resource using the Azure CLI and since I couldn't find a way to create/manage using the Azure CLI was wondering if I skipped anything in the documentations provided by Microsoft

Did get a chance to have a look at Azure REST API
Microsoft Graph API documentation also didn't have that information

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To create the App Registration, try executing the query in Microsoft Graph API:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
{
  "displayName": "AppDisplayName"
}
```

[image]

The Azure AD Application created successfully in the Portal like below:

[image]

**Refer** this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077132/issue-in-create-a-azure-bot-using-rest-api?rq=1) by *Varun Mathur* to know more on how to **create Azure Bot via Rest API**.

Based on your requirement grant the Bot **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated the access token using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientId
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://api.botframework.com/.default
```

[image]

Using the above generated access token, you can exchange messages with the channels.

For **sample** to reply the user's message, use the below format:

```json
POST https://xxx.xxx.xxx/apis/v3/conversations/****/activities/***
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "****",
        "name": "BotName"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "****",
        "name": "ConName"
   },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "***",
        "name": "UsersName"
    },
    "text": "Hello",
    "replyToId": "ID"
}
```

[image]

In the Body, select JSON like below:

[image]